# hiveserver2: error fetching result

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hue, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to query hive from hue. The query being

```
select * from table where ts='12345' LIMIT 5
```

This query runs fine from hive cli and also runs fine on supplying column name(s), but from beeswax UI, I am getting this exception when I use "Select *"

```
[HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-18]: thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:FetchResults(586)) - Error fetching results:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:338)
```

My hive version is 0.13.1. Please let me know if I am missing anything. I'll be happy to clarify.

Table was created as:

```
create table tablename{
column1 int,
somevalue string,
col3 double}
partition by ts=string
```

partition values are something like "20150101"

Comment: Whats the schema of your table please?

Comment: added it in question.

Comment: where is field somevalue in above?

Comment: Could it be because of a faulty column? My query is successfully running for other tables.

Comment: Maybe try to regexp match all the column1 that are not numbers?

Comment: it works when I do select <all column names> from table. only in case of * it throws the exception.